# Infinite job execution locking table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO resumo
            (tipo, id_tipo, qtde)
   SELECT   tipo, id_tipo, COUNT (*) qtde
       FROM tabela
      WHERE id_tipo > 400
   GROUP BY tipo, id_tipo;
COMMIT;
```

If I run it manually, it took like 30 seconds to execute.
If I put the same query into a package and create a job to run it, it just keeps running forever, locking the table `resumo`. Any ideas why this happens??

It's oracle 11g.

**EDIT**

***Package Spec:***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TESTE AS

procedure geraTabela;

End PKG_TESTE;
/
```

***Package Body:***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body PKG_TESTE AS

procedure geraTabela is

begin

    INSERT INTO resumo
                (tipo, id_tipo, qtde)
       SELECT   tipo, id_tipo, COUNT (*) qtde
           FROM tabela
          WHERE id_tipo > 400
       GROUP BY tipo, id_tipo;
    COMMIT;

end;

end PKG_TESTE;
/
```

**Job:**

```
DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
  ( job       => X 
   ,what      => 'PKG_TESTE.geraTabela;'
   ,next_date => to_date('18/05/2016 11:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   ,interval  => 'SYSDATE+60/1440 '
   ,no_parse  => FALSE
  );
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Did you actually commit (or rollback) when you ran it manually? Did you then delete the rows but not commit before trying to run it from your package? Are you sure you have a table lock, rather than it just blocking because it can't check constraints (e.g. PK) against uncommitted changes - how are you determining that the table is locked?

Comment: because the job's execution never ends... and if I try to insert something in the table (using another session) or truncate the table I get `ORA-00054 resource busy and acquire with nowait specified or timeout expired.`

Comment: It doesn't end because it's waiting for another session that has uncommitted changes. Look for the session locking the table and see if it has uncommitted changes. Or just commit/rollback in all your open sessions if you aren't sure which is which.

Comment: Before I created the job I didn't have any transactions.... after I created the job the problem gets real. its locking during job's execution.